# Typescript incorrect deduces never type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript version: 2.8.3, consider the following code snippet

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Component } from "react";
import * as React from "react";

interface ICustomer {
    id: number
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
}
interface IState {
    customers: ICustomer[]
}

class AllCustomers extends Component<{}, IState> {
    public state = {
        customers: []
    }
    public componentDidMount() {
        axios.get<ICustomer[]>(`http://localhost:8080/customers`)
        .then(resp => this.setState({customers: resp.data}))
    }
    public render() {
        const {customers}  = this.state;
        return (
            <table>
                {
                    customers.map(customer => (
                        <tr key={customer.id}>
                            <td>{customer.firstName}</td>
                            <td>{customer.lastName}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

I get compile time errors such as `customer.id` is not a field on type `never`

Somehow ... the type of `this.state.customer` is implied to be `never[]`, this is just wrong. How is an empty array as an initial value not a valid instance of the assignable array type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's silly, but when using ES7 class properties for `state`, you need to *also* type it.

```
public state: IState = {
    customers: []
}
```

if you instantiate `state` the "classic" way

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = { customers: [] }
}
```

you don't need this extra step

Comment: Pretty silly indeed, thank you though! I will accept the answer